# How can you modify the label (Text property) or a TreeNode in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, treeview, treenode

I have a TreeView with a bunch of nodes.  I have some code that is supposed to modify the label, however it has no effect.  When i step through it in the debugger, I see that the the .Text property has the correct value, but it is not reflected in the GUI.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Here's the code:

```
Public Class MyClass
    Inherits TreeNode

    Public Property Record As SomeTypeThatDefinesADataField
        Get ...
        Set ...
    End Property

    Public Sub ChangeLabel()
        If Me.TreeView IsNot Nothing Then
            Me.TreeView.LabelEdit = True
            If Not Me.IsEditing Then
                Me.BeginEdit()
            End If
            Me.Text = Me.Record.Data("Name")
            Me.EndEdit(False)
            Me.TreeView.LabelEdit = False
        End If 
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyClassThatContainsTheTreeView

    Private Sub trvRecords_AfterLabelEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.NodeLabelEditEventArgs) Handles trvRecords.AfterLabelEdit
        Me.treeView.Refresh()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense to jump through the LabelEdit hoops, just change the Text property.  The typical diagnostic of seeing the property change in the debugger but not on the screen is that you got the wrong object reference.  Changing a copy that's not visible instead of the one that the user is looking at.  It is not at all clear how you got the TreeView or Form reference in this code snippet, review your code for this.

Comment: TreeView is a property of TreeNode: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.treeview(v=VS.80).aspx).  Unless there is a bug in the framework i think we can assume that's the correct reference.  My class inherits from TreeNode.  I know i'm looking at the correct TreeNode since i can see that it has the values i expect it to hold.  Which Form reference do you refer to?  The first thing I tried was to simply set the .Text property to what I wanted it.  It didnt work and I started hunting around for all these other techniques that people seem to mention.

Comment: Yes, but what it isn't clear is that this tree node's TreeView actually refers to the tree view that the user is looking at. Clearly it is not.

Comment: i really think it's the same object.  A quick inspection in the debugger shows that the SelectedNode and RootNode properties are indeed the ones that I expect.  I have confirmed this in both methods shown above.  Is there something I am not understanding?  Are you suggesting it may be the case that I have some other TreeView with identical contents that I am inadvertently grabbing and modifying?

Comment: It is usually another instance of the form, especially in VB.NET code that uses threading.  One that isn't visible since its Show method was never called.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help.  Turns out we were both barking up the wrong tree.  The knuckle heads who worked on this code before me had apparently changed the text back to its original value after all the stuff I had done but I had not thought to continue stepping through that code because I didn't think it was related.